# How to add labels to a pull request on substrate

Tags: learning

I am new to open source and I would like to contribute to substrate. When creating a pull request I should add labels(A, B, C, and D label). How can I do so? Do the repo maintainers add these labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah only the maintainers can add the labels to a PR.